# How can I change a materials properties in my Unity c# code?

Tags: unity, materials

Hello everyone I want to change my materials tiling offset in code, but the only way I found to access it other than drag-dropping to a public field in inspector is to check by name. But I then noticed the name is suffixed with ' (Instance)' .

So it seems a little odd to me having to access it this way, is there another way that I don't know about?

```
foreach(Material m in GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials)
{
    if (m.name == "card_front (Instance)")
    {
        m.mainTextureOffset = new Vector2(value * 1/13f, (int)suit * 1/5f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the order of the materials you can just access the materials list like an array, if you only have one you can always use `[0]`. For example:

```
GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[?].mainTextureOffset = new Vector2(value * 1/13f, (int)suit * 1/5f);
```

You also don't necessarily need to worry about the `(instance)` in the name if you use [.StartWith](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netframework-4.8). This will return `true` as long as the start of the string matches but anything after the text you pass in will be ignored so `card_front2`, `card_front two`, `card_fronts (instacnce)` will all pass. For example:

```
if (m.name.StartsWith("card_front"))
```

but linking to the material in the inspector isn't necessarily a bad thing as it decouples the material from the code so you don't need to change the code if someone goes in and changes the material for a different one or changes the name.

Comment: awesome man thanks! The StartsWith() will be perfect for me.

Comment: i must say i prefer not to assign the values via Inspector if i can help it. I have had quite a few times where they have lost the values somehow and I find myself always having to reassign them if I refactor variable names etc. Still a very helpful and complete answer thanks again

Comment: @BigTLarrity note that if you rename a field, you can use the FormerlySerializedAs attribute to make sure it stays assigned in the inspector.

Comment: wow cheers Ed Marty, i will surely take a look at that